# Best way to override the WooCommerce category list Walker

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

What is the best way to override the **woocomerce** function that is in defined in the **woocomerce** plugins directory inside some class.
For example I am wanted to change the function `start_el` declared in the class `WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker`. I can change the function code in the plugin directory by the changes remains until I upgrade the **woocomerce** plugin.
How can I override it in my theme `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this...

you can create a class and extend to WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker.

```
class My_WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker extends WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker {
    public $tree_type = 'product_cat';
    public $db_fields = array ( 'parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id', 'slug' => 'slug' );

    public function start_el( &$output, $cat, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        $output .= '<li class="cat-item cat-item-' . $cat->term_id;

        if ( $args['current_category'] == $cat->term_id ) {
            $output .= ' current-cat';
        }

        if ( $args['has_children'] && $args['hierarchical'] ) {
            $output .= ' cat-parent';
        }

        if ( $args['current_category_ancestors'] && $args['current_category'] && in_array( $cat->term_id, $args['current_category_ancestors'] ) ) {
            $output .= ' current-cat-parent';
        }

        $output .=  '"><a href="' . get_term_link( (int) $cat->term_id, $this->tree_type ) . '">' . __( $cat->name, 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';

        if ( $args['show_count'] ) {
            $output .= ' <span class="count">(' . $cat->count . ')</span>';
        }
    }

}
```

then use it as like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woorei_product_categories_widget_args', 10, 1);

function woorei_product_categories_widget_args($args) {
    $args['walker'] = new My_WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Where should I create class?  `Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker' not found in...`

Comment: @НиколайАгеев it should be when woocommerce is loaded. Maybe try `plugins_loaded` hook.

Answer (score 4):

First, simply try copying `/includes/walkers/class-product-cat-list-walker.php` into your theme and include the new file. It *may* be pluggable and you can simply edit it there directly without any other effort. I'm not 100% sure.

If that fails, then you can do it by filtering [`woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php#L236) and supplying your own walker instead of trying to edit WooCommerce's.

Leave your duplicated walker file in place, but rename all the class names from `WC_Product_Cat_List_Walker` to `SO_Product_Cat_List_Walker`.

And then in your theme's `functions.php` tell the widget to use this new class as the appropriate Walker.

```
function so_32901408_cat_widget( $args ){

       // include new walker class - where ever you saved/named it
       include_once( 'wc-class-product-cat-list-walker.php' ); 
       // set the name as the new walker for the widget args
       $args['walker'] = new SO_Product_Cat_List_Walker;
       return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'so_32901408_cat_widget' );
```